Deleting files on a device
What happens to a file(s) after it has been deleted from a device?, does it remain in the operating system or it is immediately removed and the space is made available for other data?
I tried deleting files myself on a windows machine and on other platforms like android.But what surprises me is that the files I deleted can still be recovered using data recovery softwares.

The data is not removed, but the space is marked as available for new data. When new data needs the space, the system overwrites the data that was previously there with new data. This makes it so some old data can still be recovered. I could be missing part of it, but I think that's how it works.
